# How to run code when swiftui gesture recognizers begin

Tags: swiftui, gesture-recognition

SwiftUI `MagnificationGesture` and `DragGesture` have `.onChanged` and `.onEnded` APIs but nothing to check when the gesture started like in UIKit. Couple ways I thought to do it:

- `.$gestureStarted` bool in onChanged and then set it back to false in `.onEnded`
- use a gesture sequence with tap.

Am I missing some preferred way to do this? Seems like a pretty natural thing to want to check.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is special `@GestureState`, which can be used for such purpose. So, here is possible approach

```
struct TestGestureBegin: View {

    enum Progress {
        case inactive
        case started
        case changed
    }
    @GestureState private var gestureState: Progress = .inactive // initial & reset value

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Drag over me!")
        }
        .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
        .background(Color.yellow)
        .gesture(DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0)
            .updating($gestureState, body: { (value, state, transaction) in
                switch state {
                    case .inactive:
                        state = .started
                        print("> started")
                    case .started:
                        state = .changed
                        print(">> just changed")
                    case .changed:
                        print(">>> changing")
                }
            })
            .onEnded { value in
                print("x ended")
            }
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice, I hadn't come across `@gestureState`. Looks really helpful for a couple problems I'm solving. thanks for the detailed response.